# Page OnLoad not fireing changing query string

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, page-lifecycle

I have a problem that the OnLoad event is not fireing when I navigate to a page and just change the query string. If I do a postback it is called, then changing the query  string ones more OnLoad gets called.

Here is how i try. I navigate to the page OnLoad fires -> then change the query string page updates (all bound elements get updated) OnLoad does not fire -> I do a postback using a button OnLoad fires -> then change the query string OnLoad fires.

I will try to explain in more detail.

The system has log in window when I log in I navigate to an other aspx page sending two query string messages the last query string is a number (page.aspx?key=text82&key2=2010). When I get to the page the first time PageLoad event gets called and all is fine, if I in the browser change the key2 to 2011 and press enter the PageLoad does not get called but all my bound elements get updated (GrivView etc..). If I then do a postback using a button the PageLoad gets called. If I now change the 2011 back to 2010 and press Enter PageLoad is called.

I try this is firefox the PageLoad get called every time.

I tired to write a test website but I do not get the same problem, but what i found out is that in IE 8 changing the query string to the same number and pressing enter the PageLoad is not called. But doing so in firefox makes the postback fire. Here is the test code

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"     AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Welcome to ASP.NET!
</h2>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default2.aspx?t=tt&   tttttt=2010">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
</p>
<p>
    You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
        title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Navigates to

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs"
Inherits="Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><asp:Button ID="Button1"
    runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>
```

OnLoad event Default2.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += "Called " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: your queston is not clear so can you explain little bit more and also post your OnLoad() code.

Comment: What Jeevan said; Also post why you don't think the Load event is being called. Be sure to include the whole method, including the signature. Also probably include the code where you are setting up the event handler, if that's how you are doing it, and let us know where that code is, as well.

Comment: I will try to write a some code on this as it get OnLoad gets called every time when using firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. Looks like the browser cache was giving me the problem. Press F12 and cleared the cache, it works.